# Run a custom timer job only on weekdays

Tags: timer-jobs, schedule

So I want to run a timer job only on weekdays. Does anybody have any experience with a similar requirement?

I can think of two options:

1. Inherit from the SPSchedule class, and write my own custom schedule class.
2. Use the SPSchedule.FromString() method to read a custom schedule from a string. But I am not sure if I will be able to get exactly what I want from this. The only "documentation" that I have found regarding this function is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2007/01/16/spschedule-fromstring-recurrencevalue-syntax-format-for-recurrence-value.aspx)

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: create 5 weekly schedules.....

Answer (score 3):

You have to have SPJobDefinition file and the feature file to do this.

```
 public class ABCTimerJob : SPJobDefinition
    {

        public static string ABCTimerJobName = "ABC timer Job";

        public ABCTimerJob ()

            : base()
        {
            this.Title = TimerJobName ;
        }

        public ABCTimerJob(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer server, SPJobLockType targetType)

            : base(jobName, service, server, targetType)
        {
            this.Title = TimerJobName ;
        }

        public ABCTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication)

            : base(jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {

            this.Title = TimerJobName ;

        }

        public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
        {

            if (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            { 

             //your code here 
            }

        }
}
```

In feature activation event you have to do the follwing

```
        ABCTimerJob abcTimerJob = new ABCTimerJob(ABCTimerJob.ABCTimerJobName, site.WebApplication);
        SPDailySchedule schedule = new SPDailySchedule();
        schedule.BeginHour= 1;
        schedule.EndHour = 1;


        abcTimerJobTimerJob.Schedule = schedule;
        abcTimerJobTimerJob.Update();
```

Comment: Was thinking of this solution Sujeewa :)!